# Writing to WOW6432NODE from 64 bit WiX Installer

Tags: wix, windows-8.1, wix3.6

I have looked at other answers relating to writing to 32 & 64 bit registry keys from WiX, but cannot find this specific issue.

I have a WiX 3.6 installer for an IE Browser Helper Object that has been working fine until Windows 8.1 and IE11

The problem is that under the new IE8.1 Enhanced Protection Mode, I have to register a 64-bit *and* a 32-bit BHO for IE to use it.  In the past I didn't care about 64-bit IE, so I had a 32-Bit WiX project, which only installed a 32-bit DLL. On 64-bit Windows WiX correctly registered this DLL under the WOW6432NODE key.

So, I presume I need to move to a 64-Bit installers for my BHO for installation on 64-Bit Windows 8.1.

However what is the correct way, from a 64-Bit WiX MSI, to also install a 32-Bit DLL and write to the WOW6432NODE key?  I presume that WiX doesn't care that its a 32-Bit DLL, the problem is the registry keys. Does anyone know the "correct" way to register a 32-Bit DLL from a 64-Bit installer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mark the components that include the file and registry values with @Win64="no". That tells Windows Installer it's a 32-bit component and the registry writes will be redirected to Wow6432Node.